# Как вернуть мета информацию из HEAD запроса используя Retrofit2?

Tags: android, retrofit, header, request

Для взаимодействия с сервером использую ретрофит. Есть GET запрос который возвращает огромное кол-во данных. Чтобы каждый раз не съедать трафик клиента нужно проверять обновились ли данные га сервере. Для этого использую HEAD запрос к тому же эндпоинту. Проблема в том что HEAD запрос в Call<> можно положить только Void иначе выкидывает эксепшен. А при таком запросе в колбэк ничего не возвращается, так как у этого запроса нет респонса. Немного погуглив я нашел способ все же получить нужную мне метаинформацю из хедеров в Interceptor.

chain.proceed(request).header("etag"))

Но тут меня настигла очередная проблема, как без колбэка передать этот "етаг" туда откуда был сделан реквест? Должен же быть какой нибудь адекватный/элегантный способ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Retrofit2` корректно возвращает респонс в коллбек при `HEAD` запросах. Данный код у меня отлично работает:

```
Call<Void> c = service.headRequest(url);

c.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {
        response.headers();    
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

`response` не пустой и содержит в себе хедэры `response.headers()`. Если в вашем случае это не работает, то возможно, что проблема в сервере, который некорректно обрабатывает `HEAD` запросы.

Comment: Когда я логирую запрорс в Interceptor дебагом я дохожу до сточки ПЕРЕД получением респонса.
Response response = chain.proceed(request); - вот сюда уже не доходит - из чего я сделал вывод что HEAD запрос не возвращает response по причине возвращаемого типа Void(Мои догадки). Значит ли это что проблема со стороны сервера?

Comment: Ну а в самом колбеке что? `response == null`?

Comment: Сам Callback даже не вызывается. Если б вызывался, проблем бы не было:)

Comment: То есть вы просто меняете `GET` на `HEAD` и `ваш класс` на `Void` и колбек перестаёт вызываться? Очень странно. Можете показать код? Пробовали логировать запрос через `HttpLoggingInterceptor`?

Comment: не смотря на то что в Interceptor дальше указанной строчки в первом комменте исполняемый код не доходит и в onResponse ничего не приходило (из чего я и сделал вывод что колбек не отрабатывает). Оказалось что мне возвращается ответ в onFailure с ошибкой:
java.io.IOException: Content-Length and stream length disagree
Огромное спасибо за то что отозвались и разъяснили что к чему. Не понятно лишь как теперь в моей ситуации все же добыть эту метаинформацию кроме как в самом Interceptor(е).

Comment: Покажите всё же код вашего интерсептора.